# CSS variable for font-family is "invalid property" even though same string outside of variable is fine

Tags: css, font-family, css-variables

For each of the following `h1` and `h2` elements, the below CSS specifies a `font-family` in two alternative ways: (a) as the traditional string, e.g., `font-family: Tangerine,cursive;` and (b) as a previously defined CSS variable, e.g., `font-family: var(--my-font-family-cursive);`, one of which alternatives is commented out.

You can also see my code in [this CodePen Pen](https://codepen.io/jimratliff/pen/0d1df3fae650e7f72edfd7dbe0c5ed5b).

When I use the traditional string specification (commenting out the CSS-variable specification), everything works fine. Each heading is rendered in its desired font, as in this screenshot:

[image]

However, when I comment the string specification and uncomment the CSS-variable specification, the `font-family` specification is ignored entirely and the rendering defaults to my browser's user-agent spec `serif`, as in this screenshot:

[image]

Both Chrome and Firefox developer tools consider, for example, `font-family: var(--my-font-family-cursive);` to be "Invalid property value". See screenshot.

[image]

Note that I use corresponding CSS-variable syntax to define font colors `--my-font-color` and `--my-font-color-cursive` and these font colors are recognized, leading to a red `h1` and a blue `h2`.

It must be the case that I'm overlooking something stupid, but I can't figure out why my CSS-variable formulation is being rejected.

Here's just one example from the "CSS literature" that seems to endorse precisely what I'm doing: [CSS Variables — How To Use CSS Custom Properties](https://www.converticacommerce.com/ux-ui-frontend-design/css-variables-use-css-custom-properties/)
. This source gives the following example:

```
:root {
    --headings-font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

h2 {
    font-family: var(--headings-font-family);
}
```

Here's the code I describe above (which is also at [this CodePen Pen](https://codepen.io/jimratliff/pen/0d1df3fae650e7f72edfd7dbe0c5ed5b)):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>MWE: CSS variable for font-family not working</title>
<style>
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family="PT Sans");
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine);

    :root {
      --my-font-family:         "PT Sans", sans-serif ;
      --my-font-family-cursive: Tangerine, cursive ;
      --my-font-color:          red ;
      --my-font-color-cursive:  blue ;
    }

    h1, h2 { font-size: 3em ; }

    h1 {
        color:          var( --my-font-color ) ;
/*      font-family:    "PT Sans", san-serif ;  */
        font-family:    var ( --my-font-family ) ; 
    }

    h2 {
        color:          var( --my-font-color-cursive ) ;
/*      font-family:    Tangerine, cursive ;  */
        font-family:    var ( --my-font-family-cursive ) ; 
    }
</style
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Just some text</h1>
    <h2>Some more text</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have an extra space when trying to refer to the css variable with **var(--variable)**

```
h2 {
    color:          var( --my-font-color-cursive ) ;
    font-family:    Tangerine, cursive ;  */
    font-family:    var( --my-font-family-cursive ) ; 
}
```

Comment: where is the extra space? I am not able to see the difference between your code and the OP code?

Comment: @TemaniAfif took me forever.  The X in my example is where the extra space is. Example:   font-family:    varX( --my-font-family-cursive ) ;